# Format Text Bold based on the value of a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to make the text of cell A1 **bold** if the value of B1 is "a"?
Is there a formula that can achieve this or do I have to write a macro that can perform this task? Alternatively can I use conditional formatting to convert the text to **BOLD**

**Edit**
Now how would I perform the same operation if the the formatting needs to happen to the cells in column A based on the value of column B, for example if B1 = a then A1 must become Bold, B2 = b then A2 must be bold and this must happen all the way down the list.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can use conditional formatting

[image]

**FOLLOWUP (From Comments)**

For multiple cells, select the relevant range and simply remove the "$" sign before the row number to make the range relative. See Screenshot below

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response, how would i do it with multiple cells further down the sheet without having to create the rule every single time?

Comment: You simply need to remove the "$" sign before the row number after you have selected the relevant cells. Updating with a screenshot

Comment: I have edited the question please check and see if you can assist?

Comment: @MikeBarnes: I can but I have a quick question. Will it be only 10 rows and values in Col B will be from `a` to `j`? If yes, then it is easy else you will have to set separate conditional formatting for each cell.

Comment: Can you explain how to open this dialog?

Comment: @User: Home | Conditional Formatting | New Rule